# How to use user_ops in Tensorflow Android APP

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to transplantation Faster RCNN to Android device, and I meet some problems.
I build my Android project by Bazel, just like the tensorflow demo. I add the op `roi_pooling_op.cc` and `proposal_op.cc` to user_ops, but I seems Android does build user_ops, the logcat shows as following:

```
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:146 Could not create TensorFlow graph: Not found: Op type not registered 'RoiPooling'
```

I try to solve this problem, and I move `roi_pooling_op.cc` and `proposal_op.cc` to jni folder(maybe it is a bad ideal), the previous error is disappeared, but I meet another problem, outputs are all not found, I do not know why, logcat as following:

```
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:170 Output [rois] not found, aborting!
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:170 Output [bbox_pred/bbox_pred] not found, aborting!
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:170 Output [cls_prob] not found, aborting!
```

I do not know how to solve them and I to debug, could you help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there an output index on these nodes, perhaps? E.G. "rois:0" or "rois:1".

If you add a log line for node names/types to [stat_summarizer.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/util/stat_summarizer.cc#L41) in the constructor you can see what nodes are defined in your graph which might illuminate the problem.

Adding the ops to the jni directory as you've done should work fine as a quick and dirty solution, and it seems to have done so if it got you past your initial problem.